# IMAP Message UID

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, imap, rfc

In RFC3501 there is `2.3.1.1. Unique Identifier (UID)` section: `A 32-bit value assigned to each message, which when used with the unique identifier validity value (see below) forms a 64-bit value that MUST NOT refer to any other message in the mailbox or any subsequent mailbox with the same name forever.`

Most tools like `Zend\Mail` in PHP use the microtime, process id and uname to generate an UID for an email. So I get something like `1400603156.789.5617.imac.home,S=129:2,S`. This is not conform with RFC3501. Zend Mail can handle Maildir format so I don't care about managing email files on the harddisk. But if I can't handle Zend Mail's UID for RFC conform transmission I need a seperate database where I have a allocation. So I still need to manage the UIDs in a seperate place. Or is there another solution?

Br

Comment: Yes, generally an IMAP server keeps a database of UIDs separate and maps them to say, Maildir files.  They are not intrinsic to the email themselves, they are added by the server for client convenience.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/422803/61015